# Refresh a OleDbConnection to an Access DB - best practice

Tags: winforms, ms-access, refresh, oledb, oledbconnection

For reasons that is too long to explain in my .Net Win-Form Application I use a single global OleDbConnection to connect an Access DB. When I need, I open and close the connection, but generally the connection remains opened.
The problem is that sometimes the reading of the data not returns the updated datas:

```
Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sQuery, cn)
    Using rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            If rd.Read() Then
                Me.txtBrand.Text = rd.Item("MA_BRAND")
            End If
        End If
        rd.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

While if I use a new connection I get the right data:

```
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    cn.Open()
    Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sQuery, cn)
        Using rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()
            If rd.HasRows Then
                If rd.Read() Then
                    Me.txtBrand.Text = rd.Item("MA_BRAND")
                End If
            End If
            rd.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    cn.Close()
End Using
```

I have to use the global connection then my solution is this

```
cn.Close()
cn.Open()
Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sQuery, cn)
```

But I ask: there is a better solution to refresh the OledbConnection?

Thank you!
Pileggi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jet Access engine caches stuff - that's probably the problem.

Here's a good link:

- [How to Synchronize Writes and Reads with MS Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200300)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very interesting but to use these instructions I have to reference the com object "Microsoft Jet And Replication Objects 2.1 Library". Is there a way to do the same thing in ADO.Net?

Answer (score 1):

No, do not leave the connection open.  The connection pool provides for fast reconnects.

The problem you are facing with reading and writing the data is due to how [Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240317/en-us) is implemented:

> Microsoft Jet has a read-cache that is updated every PageTimeout milliseconds (default is 5000ms = 5 seconds). It also has a lazy-write mechanism that operates on a separate thread to main processing and thus writes changes to disk asynchronously.

Also, the `rd.HasRows()` isn't necessary, the `If rd.Read() Then` will return false if there aren't any rows.

To continue, the `rd.Close()` isn't necessary either since you are using the `Using...End Using` declaration.  The `End Using` will close and dispose of it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Then I have 2 questions: is there a way to work around the problem of the asynchronous update? The instructions rd.HasRows and rd.close are redundant but they shouldn't create performance problems, insn't it?

Comment: @pileggi Depends what you're doing.  You don't say why you need a global connection, but I suspect if your application has open connections everywhere, you are not following best practices.  I have never had a performance issue nor a data issue when following the open and close.  If the Jet database is on a slow network drive or connection, *maybe* that could impact performance, but you say it yourself in your post: opening and closing the connection gets you the right data.  I would keep doing that, but if you can, refactor your code to **not** keep connections open.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, now my problemi is in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518996/best-way-to-close-access-jet-oledbconnection